# convert a string into string of array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

i need to convert String to array of Strings. eg:

```
String words = "one, two, three, four, five";
```

into array like

```
String words1[];
String words1[0]="one";
       words1[1]="two";
       words1[2]="three";
       words1[3]="four";
       words1[4]="five";
```

please guide me

Comment: read Java basics. I guess all you need to initialize perhaps. `String[] words1 = new String[5]` that's all. don't use conflicting name like `Words1`, and `words1`. Also variables start with small letter.

Comment: Use your mind. that's it

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps what you are looking for is:

```
String words = "one two three four five";
String[] words1 = words.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 2):

The **exact answer** will be using `split()` function as everyone suggested:

```
String words = "one, two, three, four, five";
String words1[] = words.split(", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 String word = " one, two, three, four, five";        
 String words[] = word.split(",");
 for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(words[i]);
 }
```

if you need to remove space, you can call `.trim();` method through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here i code something may it helpful to you just take a look.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class StringTokenizing
{
 public static void main(String s[])
 {
   String Input="hi hello how are you";
 int i=0;
   StringTokenizer Token=new StringTokenizer(Input," ");
   String MyArray[]=new String[Token.countTokens()];
   while(Token.hasMoreElements())
   {
    MyArray[i]=Token.nextToken();
    System.out.println(MyArray[i]);
    i++;
   }
  }
 }
```